# How to properly use a function and it's syntax in python?

Tags: python, function

Currently I'm working on a basic text game, you can choose which weapon to fight a wolf, who's health is driven from a dictionary, same goes for statistics of the weapons you can choose from. Now what I was trying to do is set it up so I do not need to repeat the same code code for the whole damage idea and I wanted to write it down in a function, so I can call back the function for each weapon type and save on space and have less code. It would mean a lot if someone could show me how to do it, and / or any suggestions to my code and how I can make it shorter without using a lot of object oriented programming would mean the world.

Thank you for anyone helping or just reading this and taking the time of their day.

```
wolf = enemies_animals["animals"]["wolf"]["health"]


user = input("Write down your username: ")
time.sleep(0.5)

userInput = input("Welcome, for this test please choose either to attack, or to run: ")
time.sleep(0.5)

if userInput.lower() == "attack":

    time.sleep(0.5)
    weapon_type = input("Choose which type of weapon to use (melee/long_range/throwable): ")

    if weapon_type.lower() == "melee":

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon_list = []
        for key in weapons[weapon_type]:
            weapon_list.append(key)
        print(f'Choose from weapons: {weapon_list}')

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon = input("choose which weapon to use(seen from the list above): ")
        critical_chance = weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]

        if random.randint(1, 100) == weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["strength"]) / 2) * 3 * weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_multiplier"]
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")
                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

        else:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["strength"]) / 2) * 3
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")

                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

    elif weapon_type == "long_range":

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon_list = []
        for key in weapons[weapon_type]:
            weapon_list.append(key)
        print(f'Choose from weapons: {weapon_list}')

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon = input("choose which weapon to use(seen from the list above): ")
        critical_chance = weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]

        if random.randint(1, 100) == weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon][
                "strength"]) / 2) * 3 * weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_multiplier"]
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")
                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

        else:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["strength"]) / 2) * 3
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")
                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

    elif weapon_type == "throwable":

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon_list = []
        for key in weapons[weapon_type]:
            weapon_list.append(key)
        print(f'Choose from weapons: {weapon_list}')

        time.sleep(0.5)
        weapon = input("choose which weapon to use(seen from the list above): ")
        critical_chance = weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]

        if random.randint(1, 100) == weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_chance"]:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon][
                "strength"]) / 2) * 3 * weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["critical_multiplier"]
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")

                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

        else:

            total_damage = ((weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["damage"] + weapons[weapon_type][weapon]["strength"]) / 2) * 3
            attack = wolf - total_damage

            if attack <= 0:

                dead_wolf = wolf

                if random.randint(1, 5) == 5:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed a wolf with a critical hit and got it's meat! ")

                else:

                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print(f"{user} killed the wolf with a critical hit!")
            else:

                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(f"The wolf has {attack} health! ")

else:

    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f"{user}, choose to run away!")
```

Comment: Your code is 500 lines. Nobody's going to want to look through all that. Are you sure you can't make a [mre]?

Comment: I made the code smaller, completely forgot that it is 500 lines long.

Comment: Seems to me this is more suited for code review SE (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have basic questions regarding functions, there are plenty of good resources available online.

Comment: Alright thank you for your input. This is my first time writing or using anything like this so I need to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first approach, you can use Classes.
you can find a simple tutorial using this link
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it.